# Use a python variable in uwsgi's emperor.ini

Tags: python, uwsgi

I am using uwsgi to run a flask app. My index.ini looks something like this:

```
[uwsgi]
vassal_name = %n

chdir = *a specific dir*
module = project.web.%(vassal_name)
callable = app

http-socket = :8080
```

The chdir variable is something that is hard coded, which makes sense for deployment, but for local development it is a nuissance to change. So I want to make this a variable.

I have settings management set up as in [this example](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/tree/develop/project_name/project_name/settings) which is taken from Two Scoops of Django, the book. So essentially I would prefer to set the chdir variable simply in a local settings.py.

How can I get the variable from my local settings.py file and use it in the ini file?